# how to make ssh keygen work properly to set ssh keys for cloning and other purposes

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, git-bash, ssh-keygen

In the below code

```sh
############-L1 MINGW64 ~
$ which git
/mingw64/bin/git

############-L1 MINGW64 ~
$ git --version
git version 2.22.0.windows.1

############-L1 MINGW64 ~
$ which git -v
GNU which v2.21, Copyright (C) 1999 - 2015 Carlo Wood.
GNU which comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY;
This program is free software; your freedom to use, change
and distribute this program is protected by the GPL.

############-L1 MINGW64 ~
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa

############-L1 MINGW64 ~
$
```

which is run in Git Bash v2.22. I am not able to create the SSH key using the above `ssh-keygen` command. I have made sure I cleared the credentials using credential manager for Git. I have made sure to restart the computer once the installations were done. Any suggestions how can I make this work?
I need this so I can clone something from the local repository in my GitLab account and do other functionalities which require an SSH key.

Comment: What are the contents of your '~/.ssh` directory?

Answer (score 1):

The full command would be

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" -m PEM 
cd
cd .ssh
ls -alrth
```

Check that `id_rsa`/`id_rsa.pub` are created.